Create Offline Ubuntu Repository Server and Clients will get Packages from this server
I need to create Offline Package Repository for Ubuntu 22.04. And if successful later Clients (5 machines) will connect with this Repository server to fetch the packages.
Also if possible let me know how much space required to download the 22.04 packages
Thanks

Silly question, but have you looked into repository mirroring? The amount of space required will depend greatly on how much you want to mirror. It could be tens of gigabytes. It could be tens of terabytes. It’s really up to you.

I actually started using apt-mirror and with everything default it was around 580GB so i disable the deb-src and only enabled deb binary and it came down to 310GB. I dont actually use much ubuntu. But because of Two projects i have to deploy 6 machines.
Idea is to download packages once and sync it on weekly basis. If someone has better idea, please share

See at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository
